# Overwriting the AuthenticationForm class to log in with email

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I have an application in django 1.11 and I created a login by email instead of a username. In order to log in using the login form I had to overwrite the `AuthenticationForm` class and insert an email instead of username.

forms.py

```
UserModel = get_user_model()
```

Here I overwritted `AuthenticationForm` class and change username to email.

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Base class for authenticating users. Extend this to get a form that accepts
    username/password logins.
    """
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("Email address"),
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}),
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )

    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    }

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The 'request' parameter is set for custom auth use by subclasses.
        The form data comes in via the standard 'data' kwarg.
        """
        self.request = request
        self.user_cache = None
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set the label for the "username" field.
        self.username_field = UserModel._meta.get_field(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if self.fields['email'].label is None:
            self.fields['email'].label = capfirst(self.username_field.verbose_name)

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if email is not None and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, email=email, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                    code='invalid_login',
                    params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
                )
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        """
        Controls whether the given User may log in. This is a policy setting,
        independent of end-user authentication. This default behavior is to
        allow login by active users, and reject login by inactive users.

        If the given user cannot log in, this method should raise a
        ``forms.ValidationError``.

        If the given user may log in, this method should return None.
        """
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',
            )

    def get_user_id(self):
        if self.user_cache:
            return self.user_cache.id
        return None

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email', max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', max_length=50)

    field_order = ['email', 'password']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is it as it is now, is it ok? Is it possible to do it shorter / better?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override full Class as you extending `AuthenticationForm` class. You just need to override `clean()` and change `USERNAME_FIELD` to `email`